# how to use google maps heatmap feature using angular agm

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular component **@agm/core** at https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps for my latest angular 5 project to show google maps. It works great, and now I want to add google maps heatmap layer from visualization library. I can't figure out how to do it. please help

Comment: I found out there are a question already posted by someone else in the github issue forum. It seems that heatmap layer is not supported yet by @agm/core. I decide to explore pure google maps api js route. https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1289

Answer (score 17):

The following steps worked for me (*to note* that I haven't found other examples for this after long search).

1.
Install agm and googlemaps types:

```
npm install @agm/core --save
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

2.
Add "google" to types array inside compilerOptions in tsconfig. Eg:

```
"types": [
    "google"
]
```

3.
When configuring agm module, append the visualization to your api key. Eg:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    apiKey: '...' + '&libraries=visualization'
})
```

4.
In your component html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="..." [longitude]="..." (mapReady)="onMapLoad($event)">
</agm-map>
```

5.
In your component ts:

```
private map: google.maps.Map = null;
private heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer = null;

...

onMapLoad(mapInstance: google.maps.Map) {
    this.map = mapInstance;

    // here our in other method after you get the coords; but make sure map is loaded

    const coords: google.maps.LatLng[] = ...; // can also be a google.maps.MVCArray with LatLng[] inside    
    this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        map: this.map,
        data: coords
    });
}
```

Make sure your map works fine first without the heatmap code (eg, set height, api key etc).

Comment: About step №2. It should be "googlemaps" instead of "google"

Comment: instead of appending libraries, you can simply use `libraries` key of `LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral`

Comment: I needed 'import {} from 'googlemaps';' for mine to compile

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending your api key, use the libraries key for AgmCoreModule inside app.module.ts to import the visualization library as so:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: environment.googleMapsAPIKey,
  libraries: ['visualization'],
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see something like:

```
@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts is not a module
```

just create a file called index.d.ts directly within your src directory and add the following line:

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

Answer (score 0):

1-) I have installed @types/googlemaps version

> "@types/googlemaps": "^3.20.27-alpha",

in the **package.json**.

2-) Then I have used `(mapReady)="onMapLoad($event)"` on html as André Mantas says.

> ```
> <agm-map [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDoubleClickZoom]="true"
>     (mapReady)="onMapLoad($event)">
>     <agm-marker [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [title]="'Konum'" [label]="'A'"
>         (markerClick)="markerClick($event)"></agm-marker>
> </agm-map>
> ```

3-) I have added;

> ```
> AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
>   apiKey: 'your_API_key' + '&libraries=visualization'
> }),
> ```

to **app.module.ts** file.

4-) Also again as André Mantas says, I have added

> "compilerOptions": {
> "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
> "types": [
> "googlemaps"
> ]   },

to the **tsconfig.app.json** (Not google. It worked googlemaps for me.)

5-) Finally in my .ts file, i have used these things in this way;

```
import { GoogleMap } from '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types';

  private map: google.maps.Map | null = null;
  private heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer | null = null;

  getPoints() {
    return [
      //  38.722024049007054
      // 35.48524017485906
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.722024049007054, 35.48524017485906),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831, -122.441461),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687)
    ];
  }

  onMapLoad(mapInstance: google.maps.Map) {
      this.map = mapInstance;
      const coords: google.maps.LatLng[] = this.getPoints();  
      this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      map: this.map,
      data: coords
    }
    );
  }
```

It worked for me with these configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you André Mantas for your solution

I faced a number of issues related to the 'google' types. So, I added this line to the component controller

```
declare var google: any;

private map: any;
private heatmap: any;
```

and it worked